# Custom AutoCompleteTextview to fetch data from web Android

Tags: android, android-widget, custom-component, autocompletetextview

I want to implement a custom AutocompleteTextview in which i need three textview for each suggestion.

So far i have implemented custom adapter to populate the values from web. But i don't have idea to create custom AutocompleteTextview that accepts 3 textview.

Please do help me !!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide auto-complete functionality do the following steps,

1.Implement a basic searchable activity, as described in Creating a Search Interface.
Modify the searchable configuration with information about the content provider that provides custom suggestions.

2.Build a table (such as in an SQLiteDatabase) for your suggestions and format the table with required columns.

3.Create a Content Provider that has access to your suggestions table and declare the provider in your manifest.

4.Declare the type of Intent to be sent when the user selects a suggestion (including a custom action and custom data).